# Java - exec does not act like shell

Tags: java, shell, unix, exec

I want my Java program to run the command `echo "text" > /home/maxbester/test.txt` on several Unix based systems.

My code looks like:

```
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);
public String run(String cmd)  {
    String res = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        final Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        final Process p = rt.exec(cmd);
        int exitStatus = -1;
        try {
            exitStatus = p.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            L0G.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        is = p.getInputStream();

        if (exitStatus == 0) {
            if (is != null && is.available() > 0) {
                StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
                IOUtils.copy(is, stringWriter);
                res = stringWriter.toString();
            } else {
                L0G.error("InputStream is not available!");
            }
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        L0G.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        L0G.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return res;
}
```

When cmd equals `echo "text" > /home/maxbester/test.txt` and the file test.txt exists, res contains `"text" > /home/maxbester/test.txt` (and not `echo "text" > /home/maxbester/test.txt`, the **echo** disapeared) and test.txt is empty. However the exit value is 0 (so it should have worked correctly).

I run manually `echo "text" > /home/maxbester/test.txt`. Nothing was returned and the exit value was also 0.

So what's going wrong with the exec command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write text to a file in Java, you should take a look at [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) instead of relying on shell-specific details such as stream redirection.

Comment: The fact is that in a certain mode, the program uses JSch to do the work on a remote machine. So I can only use the `setCommand` method to do the job. I wanted to have a similar behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

If you want exec to behave like a shell, you must invoke a shell. E.g.

```
String shell = System.getEnv("SHELL");
cmd = shell + " -c \"echo test > /home/maxbester/test\"";
```

Your test doesn't read stderr. Maybe there was something interesting there.

Comment: My program must be able to run on a HP-UX system and bash does not exist on it. Yes I am going to update my example to read stderr.

Comment: If your destination platform supports java you should use FileWriter like @Peter said.

Comment: Updated the answer. Don't forget that all the shells must support the -c option, echo, redirection, etc. I've gotta agree with the others that you should be using FileWriter. The fact that you might want to do something similar on a remote system seems irrelevant because you will be using jsch not rt.exec. It will be different no matter what you do.

Comment: Ok I will use a FileWriter. Thanks!